# Find a NOT-antisymmetric and NOT-transitive relation on the "Real Numbers"

Tags: function, math, relation

I am searching for a relation on the real numbers.
This relation should be **NOT antisymmetric and NOT transitive**.

I found a relation, which is antisymmetric and transitive. ( <= relation)

Which relation on the real numbers is **NOT antisymmetric and NOT transitive**?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.  Ask on the mathematics exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try x R y <=> |x - y| = 1.

It is not antisymmetric because 0 R 1 and 1 R 0.

It is not transitive because 0 R 1 and 1 R 2 but not 0 R 2.